# Blank screen after logging on 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I was upgrading to 15.04 from 14.10. It was installing and after installing the files the system hung and I waited and eventually hard reset it.

Now when I reboot on Ubuntu, I can see the login screen, when I login on my user account or Guest, I only see a blue blank screen and my desktop and a mouse cursor.

Nothing happens when I click CtrlAltT and I can't see a Unity dash menu and top Gnome window.

Is it fixable via the Virtual terminal? Can someone please throw some pointers around as I need to do uni work. Thanks. Awaiting response.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I don't remember the procedure much.

- Got onto tty1 via `Ctrl+Alt+F1`
- Ran `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` but I got a `dpkg --configure -a` error
- So I ran `dpkg --configure -a`. The problem fixed
- After that I ran `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` and then `unity`
- I didn't have gnome so I installed `sudo apt-get install gnome` too
- Rebooted in lost hopes, it booted up correctly and now i'm using it, can't be more happy!